# Tesla Coil audio music player circuit analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, tesla-coil

**Here is the circuit:**
[image: circuit]

**Here is it being powered up and wirelessly turning on a lamp.**

[image]

Here are my questions:

How does it actually work?

- I do know that 1T ( The red wire ) is being switched ON/OFF by Q2, BD243 which induces a voltage to 350T, which is about (VCC-18v) x 350 = 6.3kv. (I don't think 6.3kv is high enough to wireless powering on a lamp.)
- What is the purpose of Q1? It's a N-channel 68 V, 0.0082 Ω, 98 A Mosfet.
- LED1 is a red led diode. If it's blocking the 350T, how does circuit oscillate? ie, how does 350T turn off Q2?
- I don't know how the audio-in work either, but it does work quite well.

Last but not least, After googling about Tesla Coil circuits, I either find very complex or very simple circuits. Is there a middleman out there?

Comment: *sigh* This is not a Tesla coil. That's why you're not finding what you're looking for. It's just a high frequency oscillator. The bulb is being lit by a high frequency electrical field emitted by the coil.

Comment: @DerStrom8 if it's not, then can you show me a real Tesla coil. according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_coil, this is a Tesla coil. "The term "Tesla coil" is applied to a number of high voltage resonant transformer circuits." It's so hard to find a "REAL" modern Tesla coil, probably because the guy invented it is very very old!!! He doesn't use modern component as much as I do??!!

Comment: This is not a resonant transformer circuit, that is what sets it apart from actual Tesla coils. It's just a high frequency oscillator, as I said before. I have built numerous *actual* Tesla coils myself, the most common "modern" Tesla coil is a dual-resonant solid-state Tesla coil, which uses solid-state components and two tuned resonant circuits to generate the extremely high voltage output. All this circuit does is use a MOSFET with feedback to turn it on and off at a very high frequency to generate an electrical field that excites the gases in the CFL lamp

Comment: Also, the symbol for C1 is drawn backwards. the curved "plate" is the negative, not the straight one.

Comment: And thirdly, Wikipedia is hardly a source to rely on and to cite. Anyone can go in and write a Wikipedia article, and that's exactly what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Simple induction.  I am amazed  and impressed that you have achieved this with low-voltage components.  But they is also why the CFL needs to e close to the transmitting (coupling) coil.

The Tesla concept is pulsed electric voltages fed into a coil that radiates it.  The switching determines the frequency of the pulses.  Traditional tesla coils use a spark gap so the pulses are very quickly turned on and off.  Your transister is doing that part for you.  The audio part of the circuit is frequency modulating the pulse stream so you can hear it.

Then the mercury atoms in the tube vibrate with the pulses, giving off UV energy.  The phosphor lining is what converts the UV to visible, and can be many different colors.

Word of warning:  If you break a CFL be sure not to step on it barefoot.  Mercury is toxic.

You asked about various other components, and since you say it is working I don't have time to completely analyze the circuit,  But that's the basic principle for how it works.

You asked about finding a middleman, and I would say you have found it.  I have done music feeds into Tesla coils but always used the sparks as the audio transducer so I could hear it.  That means using a smaller induction coil with very high voltages inducing currents into a resonant secondary coil.

The difficulty with inducing music in those is that  you need a solid-state "spark gap" that can be frequency modulated at very high current levels.    That's a whole lot more work (and a lot more dangerous) than what you are doing.

Using near-field radiation into a CFL is a neat idea.  I'll have to try this myself.

Comment: Neon light also works, but the seller of this kit states that it also able to light up stuff and led. Yep, it can burn a toothpick easily, but it can't light up a led. While it's fun to play with, I really want to understand how it really works because I want to design my own circuit someday.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the purpose of Q1? It's a N-channel 68 V, 0.0082 Ω, 98 A Mosfet.
>
> I don't know how the audio-in work either, but it does work quite well.

- The (AC) audio signal from the 3.5 mm jack passes trough C1 (which is there to block DC from flowing to or from the audio source) to the gate of the MOSFET. The MOSFET acts as a [common drain amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_drain): It will conduct more whenever the source voltage falls significantly below the gate voltage, bringing the source voltage back up in the process, and conduct less when the source voltage rises towards the gate voltage, bringing the source voltage down. This topology is also known as a "source follower" for this reason, as the source voltage follows the gate voltage. R1 and R3 are biasing resistors that keep the gate (and indirectly the amplifier output/source) at an optimum average DC voltage.

  This effect is further enhanced by the fact that the output of this amplifier is also the reference voltage of the audio signal, providing voltage gain as well: A rise in the source voltage (caused by an increase in the gate voltage) will also increase the voltage of the audio source relative to the rest of the circuit, in turn raising the gate voltage in a positive feedback loop.

  In other words, Q1 varies the supply voltage of the rest of the circuit in sync with the audio waveform, amplitude modulating the high voltage output in the process.

> LED1 is a red led diode. If it's blocking the 350T, how does circuit oscillate? ie, how does 350T turn off Q2?

- Indeed it is blocking the secondary (the winding of 350 turns), but this is of no consequence. During positive half cycles the LED will conduct and light up, during negative cycles the LED has no chance blocking *several kilovolts* brute forcing their way trough, so the LED just enters [avalanche breakdown mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_breakdown) and conducts in reverse anyway. It doesn't suffer significant damage, because the current is so low and diodes are fairly rugged semiconductors unlike e.g. MOSFET gate oxide layers found in ICs.